# Меню в два столбца с разделительными линиями

Tags: css

Требуется сделать меню в два столбца. Количество пунктов заранее неизвестно. Пункты меню разделяются горизонтальными линиями, линий сверху и снизу каждого столбца не должно быть.

Без учета последнего требования получается вот такое решение:

```css
 .wrapper {
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 400px;
 }
 ul.menu {
  -webkit-column-count: 2;
  -moz-column-count: 2;
  column-count: 2;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 0;
 }
 ul.menu > li {
  border-top: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 5px 0;
 }
```

```html
 <div class="wrapper">
  <ul class="menu">
   <li>Option 1</li>
   <li>Option 2</li>
   <li>Option 3</li>
   <li>Option 4</li>
   <li>Option 5</li>
   <li>Option 6</li>
   <li>Option 7</li>
   <li>Option 8</li>
   <li>Option 9</li>
  </ul>
 </div>
```

Как убрать линию у первого элемента в левом столбце понятно (`:first-child` или `li + li`), но нужно убрать линию у двух пунктов в первой строке.

Высоты пунктов меню могут изменяться (раскрываются пункты подменю), поэтому который из пунктов окажется верхним во втором столбце неизвестно и применять стиль по порядковому номеру не получится.

Answer (score 1):

Несколько неуклюжее решение:

```css
 .wrapper {
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 400px;
 }
 ul.menu {
  -webkit-column-count: 2;
  -moz-column-count: 2;
  column-count: 2;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 0;
 }
 ul.menu > li {
  border-top: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 5px 0;
 }
 /* answer */
 .wrapper {
  position: relative;
 }
 .wrapper:before {
  background: #fff;
  content: '';
  height: 3px;
        /* сделать линию в один пиксел не достаточно. На планшете с
           высоким разрешением проявятся тонкие полоски */
  position: absolute;
  top: 19px;
        /* из-за высоты в 3px смещение задаем за 1px меньше чем
           величина верхнего отступа*/
  width: 100%;
 }
 ul.menu > li {
  -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
        /*иначе в Chrome на второй столбец переносится нижний padding*/
 }
```

```html
 <div class="wrapper">
  <ul class="menu">
   <li>Option 1</li>
   <li>Option 2</li>
   <li>Option 3</li>
   <li>Option 4</li>
   <li>Option 5</li>
   <li>Option 6</li>
   <li>Option 7</li>
   <li>Option 8</li>
   <li>Option 9</li>
  </ul>
 </div>
```

Недостатки решения - "магические" числа и жестко заданный цвет полоски, который придется менять, если поменяется фон меню.

Comment: А почему вы создаёте псевдоэлемент у .wrapper, а не у ul.menu? Есть какая-то серьёзная причина или просто дело вкуса?

Comment: Нет причины. Вопрос возник при модификации чужой верстки и обертка уже была. А в принципе будет работать и вариант с ul.menu:before

Answer (score 1):

```
.wrapper {
        background: #fff;
        border: 1px solid #000;
        width: 400px;
    }
    ul.menu {
        -webkit-column-count: 2;
        -moz-column-count: 2;
        column-count: 2;
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 20px;
        padding: 0;
    }
    ul.menu > li {
        border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
        padding: 5px 0;
    }
    ul.menu > li:last-child {
        border-bottom: none;
    }
```

.

```
<div class="wrapper">
        <ul class="menu">
            <li>Option 1</li>
            <li>Option 2</li>
            <li>Option 3</li>
            <li>Option 4</li>
            <li>Option 5</li>
            <li>Option 6</li>
            <li>Option 7</li>
            <li>Option 8</li>
            <li>Option 9</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: Останется полоса под последним пунктом в первом столбце

Comment: Тогда эксперементируйте с `:nth-child` нужны подобрать высоту блока с учетом `border` элементов.

Comment: Для чего подбирать высоту блока? И чем поможет `:nth-child` (учитывая что мы не знаем заранее который из них будет нижним слева или верхним справа)?

Comment: Ну если мы знаем высоту блока и высоту дочерних, можно вычислить

Comment: Ну это только если через JS. Еще раз повторюсь: заранее неизвестно сколько их и какова их высота. Это меню в шаблоне CMS. Категории берутся из базы и пользователь может их добавлять или удалять. Наименования могут быть в 1-3 строки. На месте некоторых пунктов будет подменю, которое показывается только на соответствующих страницах. Эти ограничения есть в вопросе